# Using Tilt to render Sass template with Compass

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass, tilt

I am working on a static site generator (Staticpress) that uses Tilt to handle rendering. Out of the box, Tilt can render sass just fine; however when I render a sass template that tries to `@import compass/reset/utilities`, Sass raises a `Sass::SyntaxError`. I can pass extra options to Tilt when I call `#render` (which will be passed on to Sass), but what options should I pass to make Compass available?

**Update:**

I have a one-line test file that only has `@import "compass/reset/utilities"` in it. The error I get when running my test is `Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset/utilities`, along with a stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Tilt has a way to pass options through to the rendering engine. To use Compass, pass `Compass.sass_engine_options` to `Tilt.new`.